# Punctuating an Initialized/Abbreviated Last Name

Tags: american-english, punctuation, abbreviations, names, nicknames

What is the proper method, in American English, to punctuate a name that's been abbreviated to an initial? I.e., "Dr. S," if the full last name was something like, say, "Syzlowski," or someone named, say, "Tiberius," who prefers to be simply called "T?"

Specifically, would there be a period after the initial?

--

> "Dr. S.," she called, "there's someone here to see you."

vs.

> "Dr. S," she called, "there's someone here to see you."

--

> "He's not here," T. answered.

vs.

> "He's not here," T answered.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The finer points of punctuation are a matter of style; adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application. That said, periods used to indicate abbreviation are not generally removed except when final punctuation is also a period.

Comment: Wikipedia has "Robin S." but "Jamie T"; this may reflect American vs English usage, or personal preference. If in doubt, if someone prefers to be known as "T" or "T.", ask them which they prefer.

Answer (score -1):

## Formal: **T.** *(initial with a period)*

If you want to clearly indicate that it is short for a word, use the period. Then there will be no question in the reader's mind.

The question is about being "proper"...

### What is the ***proper*** method, in American English?

If you are trying to use the "proper" form accepted in most style books and in school up through undergraduate, use the period.

[Chicago style forum](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/forum.html?php=showthread&tid=5895&pid=32644):

> ...if you're following Chicago, you also want a space between the initials: O. J. Simpson.

[AP Style](https://twitter.com/apstylebook/status/588437999517466625):

> AP style tip: Use periods and no space when an individual uses initials instead of a first name: H.L. Mencken.

From [this business style standard](http://upwritepress.com/_blog/Write_for_Business_-_Blog/post/Using_Punctuation_Period_with_Initials_and_Abbreviations_/):

> A period should be placed after an initial and after most abbreviations.

*(In higher education, teachers will rightly take more license with their styles, so always ask the instructor.)*

But, this does depend on the style standards for your specific publication. If you control your own style standards and want the proper, formal, school-taught form, then use the period, ***T.*** answered **S.**

### Why it matters: *Harry S Truman*

An abbreviated name needs the period to indicate that it represents something longer.

On [Harry S Truman from the National Park Service](https://www.nps.gov/hstr/faqs.htm):

> In Truman's autobiography, he stated, "My Grandfather Truman's name was Anderson Shipp Truman and my Grandfather Young's name was Solomon Young, so I received the S for both of them." He once joked that the S was a name, not an initial, and it should not have a period. The park service does not use a period. However many official documents and his presidential library all use a period. Both are correct.

[This article](https://www.infoplease.com/askeds/what-was-trumans-middle-name) clarifies that names should have a period: (*emphasis* added)

> There has been controversy since 1962, when Truman told reporters that they should not use a period after the S, because it didn't stand for anything. He may have been joking; he himself often wrote his middle initial followed by a period. At any rate, *the ruling of most style manuals is to include the period.*

If an ***American*** *(back to your question)* president does it, then it surely affects ***American*** English.

#### Middle name: *F*

Also, I have a friend who has a third-generation name, from grandfather to grandson, with the middle name "F", the letter *F* being the entire middle name. He, his father, and grandfather don't use the period either. When their school teachers ask, *"Why no period?"* with the answer that the full middle name is only one letter, the school teachers don't use the period either. There's your demonstrable formal, "proper" answer.

### When *not* to use the period

Knowing when to use the period might be easier by knowing when *not* to. [Grammarly](http://An%20acronym%20is%20pronounced%20as%20a%20single%20word) explains the reasoning behind non-period abbreviations well: (**bold** added)

> An **acronym** is pronounced as a single word, rather than as a series of letters. NASA, for instance, is an acronym.

...

> **Initialisms** are similar to acronyms in that they are also formed using the first letter of each word in a longer phrase. Unlike acronyms, however, initialisms are pronounced as a series of letters. NFL (National Football League), for example, is pronounced en-eff-ell.

...But, you're not going for that. You want to indicate that the single letter stands for a full last name. Consider being appropriate to the occasion: (*emphasis* added)

> One thing to remember about abbreviations is that certain ones are considered informal. *If you are writing something very formal, it’s better to err on the side of spelling things out.* The other thing to remember is that some readers may not know what an abbreviation means. If the abbreviation is obscure or unfamiliar, *make sure to explain what it means the first time you use it.*

...Using the period would help explain that it is a name.

---

*Summary among many styles:*

The main styling rule is "consistency"; the second rule is "sensibility".

In the culture that accepts non-words like "ain't", "***Dr. S***" is all too common and is generally okay where style isn't so vital, but that doesn't make it "proper", which was your Question.

Most people won't care, but if either clarity or formality is your goal, use the period. No style guide would say you are wrong to do so.

Comment: "All to common"... in advice to learners...

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you liked that?

Comment: Did you mean "all **too** common"?

Comment: Oh, yeah! You caught that. Why not just edit it?

Comment: When the 'culture' gets big enough, it tells the rest of the population what constitutes  a word.

Comment: Where did you get that story about Truman? I've read that his parents gave him the "S". It is commonly written "Harry S. Truman" and apparently that's how *he* signed his name. https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/harry-truman-middle-name/

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, I did some fact checking myself and included two sources, one from the US govt., that includes the question of periods with a name's initials. Truman, being a president, does affect "precedent" with things like this, it is included in the discussion, so I wantes to keep it. Thanks for the fact checking. This was one of my earlier answers before I got the habit of heavy sourcing. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm adding back my upvote after your inclusion of what the style guides say

Comment: fwiw, my dad's birth certificate listed J as his first name and B as his middle name, and his parents and kinfolk called him JB his/their entire life, which sufficed until dad entered the military and they said that initials as names weren't gonna cut it... so he named himself! unfortunately I don't recall if the birth certificate used dots/periods after the letters. I don't know why they would have, since they weren't short for anything

Comment: American media (New Yorker, NY Times, etc) seems to use "Malcolm X" without the period, and the same thing for movie director "McG" (short for McGinty) and movie "The 5000 Fingers of Dr. T" (although Wikipedia has a period after T). Not sure what other names to check.